# More efficient way to convert units?

Tags: android

I am creating a calculator for Android that is currentlly planned to have a basic calculator (will be more advanced when I get more experienced in adnroid development), Trigenometry functions, Fraction functions, and unit conversion.

My question is, with the large amount of units that can be converted - is there a simple/effective way to accomplish the task rather than using methods or static final variables?

Currently I am using methods to accomplish the conversion, but that is going to be a hell of alot of methods for every single combination.

Here is an example of just converting from Kilometres to other length units:

```
public double KMtoM (double KM) {return KM * 1000;}
public double KMtoCM (double KM) {return KM * 100000;}
public double KMtoMM (double KM) {return KM * 1000000;}
public double KMtoMICRON (double KM) {return KM * 1000000000;}
public double KMtoMILIMICRON (double KM) {return KM * 1000000000000L;}
public double KMtoANGSTROM (double KM) {return KM * 10000000000000L;}
public double KMtoIN (double KM) {return KM * 39370.07874015748031496062992126;}
public double KMtoFT (double KM) {return KM * 3280.8398950131233595800524934383;}
public double KMtoMILE (double KM) {return KM * 0.621371;}
public double KMtoMIL (double KM) {return KM * 39370078.74015748031496062992126;}
```

Since I am new to Android Development, I figured I would ask here and maybe learn something new.

Comment: this open source project may give you some ideas: https://github.com/physphil/UnitConverterUltimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose for example unit of Meters as a central unit. Then instead of converting everything between each other, just convert whatever you have to Meters first and then from meters to another unit